# Комментарий с лицензией вверху кода, вводится автоматически? Или есть некий способ "иначе"?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, лицензирование

**Подскажите, эти комментарии создаются вручную или через какой-то скрипт? Было бы очень глупо вводить во все файлы ручками, поэтому скорее всего есть какой-то скрипт? Но не могу ничего об этом найти, спасибо.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**И обязательно эти коменты вписывать? К примеру у меня MIT лицензия в проекте. Имеет ли смысл делать такие комментарии для MIT?**

Comment: Где-то в IDE есть настройка автогенерации такого текста при создании файла для класса. Смысла это писать нет - достаточно где-то просто сказать о лицензии и всё

Comment: В Студии/Идее: `File | Settings | Editor | Copyright | Copyright Profiles` - здесь создаём профиль с текстом лицензии, на уровень выше выбираем его. Смысл в том, что пользователю кода не придётся заморачиваться с указанием авторства, когда он скопирует отдельные классы в свой проект. Если у него настроена автогенерация, то может и не заметить, что поставил свой копирайт на ваш код.

Comment: Ничего, кроме разбухания размера файла, эти комментарии не дадут. Подобные вставки и лицензирование вообще - замануха крупных контор, которые смогут отстаивать (получая профит) свои авторские права и условия лицензии.

Comment: @user7860670, у вас однобокое понимание. Лицензия еще и определяет пределы вашей ответственности за распространяемый код.
Автор, вы именно в виде исходного кода распространяете проект?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, да

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это скорее юридический вопрос, чем технический.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, а вы его читали?

Comment: @woesss, да, особенно последние два вопроса. На первый вы автору ответили.